# Group by and fill missing datetime values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, machine-learning

What I'm just trying is to group a Pandas Dataframe by contract and date, and fill missing datetime values.

My input is this:

```
contract         datetime             value1          value2
   x       2019-01-01 00:00:00          50              60
   x       2019-01-01 01:00:00          30              60
   x       2019-01-01 02:00:00          70              80
   y       2019-01-01 00:00:00          30              100
```

What I want to do is to have all possible datetimes (from 00:00:00 to 23:00:00) for each contract, and fill missing values with NaN or None.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) per groups with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and lambda function:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

f= lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min().floor('d'),
                                      .index.max().floor('d')+pd.Timedelta(23, 'H'),freq='H'))
df1 = (df.set_index('datetime')
         .groupby('contract')
         .apply(f)
         .drop('contract', axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to the same if you have two datetimes that are the same?

Comment: @FranG91 - It is duplicates, so bet is first create unique value columns like `df = df.groupby(['contract','datetime']).sum()` or `df = df.groupby(['contract','datetime']).mean()` and then apply this solution - solution need unique datetimes per groups

Comment: Thank you, but this will give me sumed or average values for each datetime, isn't it?
Do you know if there is way to add one hour to the duplicated datetime and to the following ones?
Imagine we have hour 2 duplicated, so we will turn the duplicated hour into hour 3, and the following ones should have one hour added too, so we will have finally 25 hours, instead of 24. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FranG91 - Can you create new question? Because it is not so easy.