# Group by and fill missing datetime values with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question comes from this one: [Group by and fill missing datetime values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352953/group-by-and-fill-missing-datetime-values)

What I'm just trying is to group a Pandas Dataframe by contract, check if there are duplicated datetime values and fill this ones. If there are duplicates, there will be a total of 25 hours, and if not, 24.

My input is this:

```
contract         datetime             value1          value2
   x       2019-01-01 00:00:00          50              60
   x       2019-01-01 02:00:00          30              60
   x       2019-01-01 02:00:00          70              80
   x       2019-01-01 03:00:00          70              80
   y       2019-01-01 00:00:00          30              100
```

With this Dataframe my output should be something like this:

```
contract         date              value1                     value2
   x           2019-01-01    [50,NaN,30,70,70,NaN,Nan...]    [60, NaN, Nan...]
   y           2019-01-01    [30, NaN, Nan...]               [100, NaN, NaN...]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need lists?

Comment: yes, so if I have all my datetimes ordered I can create a list with a lambda function, the basic problem is to get all my datetimes when there are duplicated ones.

Comment: can you give a complete summary of the output that you expect from the example, replacing elipsis

Comment: In the first row (first contract) we will have 25 values in the list, because there are two hours duplicated, meanwhile in the second contract we will have 24 values, because there are no hours duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is first create lists for possible use previous solution:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df = df.groupby(['contract','datetime']).agg(list)

f= lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min().floor('d'),
                                     x.index.max().floor('d')+pd.Timedelta(23, 'H'),
                                     freq='H', name='datetime'))
df1 = (df.reset_index('contract')
         .groupby('contract')['value1','value2']
         .apply(f)
         .reset_index())
```

Last grouping by `contract` and dates and flatten lists with `chain.from_iterable`:

```
from  itertools import chain

df2 = (df1.groupby(['contract', df1['datetime'].dt.date])
         .agg(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(y if y==y else [y] for y in x)))
         .reset_index()
         )
print (df2)
  contract    datetime                                             value1  \
0        x  2019-01-01  [50, nan, 30, 70, 70, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...   
1        y  2019-01-01  [30, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, n...   

                                              value2  
0  [60, nan, 60, 80, 80, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...  
1  [100, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
```

Test lenghts:

```
print (df2[['value1','value2']].applymap(len))
   value1  value2
0      25      25
1      24      24
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, I think this might work:

`df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

then just groupby from there.

(full disclosure, I didn't double-check but I think that's the appropriate format to get YYYY-MM-DD) also to avoid confusion, it might be worth renaming `['datetime']` to something else.