# Add missing datetime rows and check duplicates

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I'm relatively new to pandas and I hope you could give me a hand ;-)

I want to group a pandas dataframe by `name_id` and `datetime`, adding also missing datetime values (`NaN`).

Input example:

```
name_id   datetime          value
 A      23/01/2020 0:00:00   100
 A      23/01/2020 1:00:00   98
 A      23/01/2020 2:00:00   96
 A      23/01/2020 3:00:00   99
 A      23/01/2020 3:00:00   99
 A      23/01/2020 4:00:00   98
 A      23/01/2020 5:00:00   99
 B      23/01/2020 0:00:00   144
 B      23/01/2020 1:00:00   324
 B      23/01/2020 2:00:00   367
 B      23/01/2020 3:00:00   368
 B      23/01/2020 6:00:00   364
```

First of all I need to complete missing datetime values per `name_id`. If there is any missing hour from one day (00:00 to 23:00) add new row with this hour and corresponding Nan 'value'.

Also I need to remove duplicates. Due to time change some days could be with 25 hours so I need to remove them for this hour/day and `name_id`.

The output would be like this :

```
name_id         date              v                    
   A           2020-01-23    [132, 76, 56, 77, 81, 100, NaN, Nan, ......]    
   B           2020-01-23    [44, 24, 165, 267, NaN, Nan, 263, Nan, Nan...]
```

I found a similar case here but it does not work for me when I apply this part of the code, it deletes my name_id column :-(

[Group by and fill missing datetime values with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373305/group-by-and-fill-missing-datetime-values-with-duplicates)?

```
df1 = (
    df.reset_index('name_id')
    .groupby('name_id')['value']
    .apply(f)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fill_datetimes(df):
    daterange = pd.date_range(
        df.index.min().floor('d'), 
        df.index.max().floor('d')+pd.Timedelta(23, 'h'), 
        freq='H', name='datetime')
    # if you only want to de-duplicate on datetime, 
    # use `df.drop_duplicates("datetime").reindex(daterange)`
    return df.drop_duplicates().reindex(daterange)

filled_df = df.set_index("datetime")\
    .groupby('name_id')['value']\
    .apply(fill_datetimes)\
    .reset_index()

filled_df.groupby(
    ['name_id', 
     pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')]
)['value'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
name_id  datetime  
A        2020-01-01    [2.0, nan, nan, nan, 29.0, nan, 68.0, 83.0, 99...
B        2020-01-01    [nan, 42.0, 45.0, 99.0, nan, 11.0, nan, nan, n...
Name: value, dtype: object
```